# Get Attribute from object; 'Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttribute'

Tags: c#, xamarin

I've been using the guides on microsofts website but unable to put them into practice. I've been using this code here:

```
public static async Task<T> LoadObject<T>(string objectId) where T : DBObject
{
    ...
    TestAttribute MyAttribute = (TestAttribute)System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T), typeof(TestAttribute));
    ...
}
```

But this causes the error below; `Attribute` only seems to have the methods `Equals` and `ReferenceEquals`. I'm thought I might be missing a reference but I've included all that was in the samples.

```
Error CS0117: 'Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttribute' (CS0117) (TestProject)
```

Comment: Is that really the error message here? It doesn't match the code you show.

Comment: I had `T` instead of `typeof(T)` as a method param, I've updated it for that. But that is definitely the error I am getting.

Comment: Oh wait, I just noticed you're using Xamarin. That's not using the normal full fat .Net Framework. Try this: `TestAttribute MyAttribute = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<TestAttribute>();`

Comment: what's your framework version? if it's .net core 1.1 , it hasn't been implemented there ( it's included in net core 2.0 though) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute?view=netcore-1.1

Comment: @DavidG that didn't solve it and gave me another error (maybe because it's a PCL library?). It did give me the clue to solving it: ` TestAttribute MyAttribute = (TestAttribute)typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute(typeof(TestAttribute));`

Comment: @rustem If I right click the project -> options -> build -> general, the target framework is .NET Portable, PCL 4.5 - Profile 111

Comment: Note I change it to use the generic version of `GetCustomAttribute` which means you don't need to do the cast too.

Comment: decompile System.Runtime.dll and you'll see it hasn't been implemented there. Use something like typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<>()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using Xamarin, you're running the Mono Framework which means you don't have access to the full .Net Framework library as you might expect. One of the changes is reflection, and you need to change your code to this:

```
TestAttribute MyAttribute = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<TestAttribute>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't find it because it hasn't been implemented there. See below decompiled System.Runtime.dll.

```
namespace System
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
  public abstract class Attribute
  {
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
       return false;
    }

    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
       return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Use something like

```
typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<>()
```

instead